# React Native (Android) Google Sign In Error (Developer Error)

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

Tried all available solutions on the internet but still getting same error, also cross Checked SHA1 key. Used both methods Firebase and Google Developer console but all in vain.

Comment: Add the error what you are getting. Post your code where the errors is occurring. No one will ever be able to understand your problem if you just say You got some sort of error.

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue,
For me I am using [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin)  with firebase.

My problem was SHA certificate fingerprints on firebase console is different with my project keystore.

U can check it by run this command to make sure your SHA on firebase and keystore is same.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by no/invalid App Signature. You most likely use bare workflow, since you're getting this error, because expo does this for you when you build the app. To achieve the same in bare workflow

1. Drop your android folder in Android Studio
2. In Upper toolbar click Build >> Generate Signed APK
3. Choose APK from given options.
4. Type in your KeyStore informations.
5. After building an app, you must be able to use google sign in.